# I can't install anything in Ubuntu 17.04 (neither terminal or install button work)

Tags: package-management

I've just installed Ubuntu onto this laptop, and when attempting to install any file, the install button in Ubuntu Software does nothing when clicked. I've tried the following lines of code suggested in other answer threads with my problem, and none of them work:

```
sudo apt install
```

and

```
sudo dpkg -i *package-name*
```

The former yields an error message with "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)."

The latter results in "dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'filename.deb': No such file or directory"

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: @Pilot6  I just can't install anything in general.

Comment: I can answer "in general": You are doing something wrong. If you explain what are you doing, then it will be possible to help.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for the first is :

```
sudo apt install package-name
```

where package-name obviously is the name of the package you want to install. Refer to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt.8.html) for full info about it. If this is what you did, try the command given in the error message (`apt --fix-broken install` ).

For the second one, the error message is clear: your system does not find the file you specified.  You should try something like:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/filename.deb
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i /Files/Downloads/filename.deb` didn't work. It simply outputs:  dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/Files/Downloads/filename.deb': No such file or directory

Comment: Then it means that there is no such file with this path: `/Files/Downloads/filename.deb`. It is very unlikely that such a directory may exist. Where is the "Files" directory?

Comment: It is unlikely that a directory `/Files` exist on your system. Is it in your Home directory or where? Try `~/Files/Downloads/filename.deb` if this is the case.

Comment: @Pilot6  I see my mistake now, but `/Home/Downloads/filename.deb` still yields the same error message

Comment: This is still a wrong path. The correct may be `~/Downloads/filename.deb`. There is no `/Home`, or `/Files`. The leading `/` means that it is in the root of the filesystem. But this is not the case.

Comment: @Pilot6  It seemed to have actually attempted to install, but I got an error message saying "Errors were encountered while processing:
 opera-stable". The particular file I'm testing this on at the moment, that I want to install, is opera-stable_46.0.2597.39_amd64.deb

Comment: This is completely a different issue. Most likely `sudo apt install -f` will fix it.

Comment: You need to ask another question where you need to explain what are you installing and post the exact error message.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Ubuntu (and most, if not all *nix OSes) is case-sensitive. `/Files` and `/files` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong path. Copy the `filename.deb` to your Home directory.

Then you can install it by

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/filename.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

because a terminal is opened it your Home directory by default.

If you copy it to the `Downloads` directory located in your Home, then the command will be

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/filename.deb
```

The `~/` means your Home directory.

The `/` means the root of the file system.